# Linux bc defines PI as 99

Tags: bc, math

I'm using bc in Ubuntu Linux. It has a pre-defined constant PI that's set to 99.
Why does bc define PI to be 99 instead of 3.14159...?

Answer (score 19):

There is no built-in constant π in `bc`. If invoked with the `-l` option, some built-in *functions* become available, allowing you to evaluate π trigonometrically – [the man page](http://man.he.net/man1/bc) includes this example:

> #### EXAMPLES
>
>   In the shell, the following will assign the value of π to the shell variable
>   `pi`
>   .
>
> ```
> pi=$(echo "scale=10; 4*a(1)" | bc -l)
> ```

What is happening when you try to evaluate `PI` is the result of input base conversion, as described in the texinfo documentation for GNU bc (here version 1.07.1):

> …   `bc` converts constants into
> internal decimal numbers using the current input base, specified by the
> variable *`IBASE`.*

noting that

> …   For multi-digit numbers, `bc` changes all
> input digits greater or equal to *`IBASE`*
> to the value of *`IBASE`*−1.  This
> makes the number `ZZZ` always be the largest 3 digit number
> of the input base.

Correspondingly, in the default `ibase=10`, conversion of any pair of non-decimal digits results in decimal 99.

Earlier versions of GNU `bc` have a maximum `ibase` value of 16, and only make provision for characters in the set [0-9A-F]; characters outside of this range result in an error condition in that case. 
You can see this the [`bc` Command Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/html_mono/bc.html) version 1.06,
which also contains the above passages.

Comment: What version of `bc` is this? I don't get this behaviour on `bc 1.06.95`. Here, `PI` gives me two lines of error: `(standard_in) 1: illegal character: P` and `(standard_in) 1: illegal character: I`. Digging harder, it seems that your rule applies here only to the letters `A`-`F`, and even then only partly: `F` -> `15` (hex?) but `FF` -> `99`

Comment: @roaima tested on GNU bc 1.07.1

Comment: Thanks. Definitely a change in behaviour, actual and (now that I read it) documented. In 1.06.95 the maximum value of `ibase` is 16, and your description involving `ZZZ` is here notated with `FFF`.

Comment: Thanks for the update @roaima I have added a note to that effect

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure `bc` have Pi number internally, but you can always calculate it on this way:

```
4*a(1)
```

function `a(x)` is actualy *arctangent*

Comment: This is even the first example in the “EXAMPLES” section of the man page: `echo "scale=10; 4*a(1)" | bc -l` (you need to specify `-l` to get the `a()` function).

Answer (score 5):

No, there is no (math) *constant PI defined as 99* in (any) `bc`.

What is customary in `bc` is to interpret uppercase letters as constant numeric values. (Lowercase letters are variable names).

Even in POSIX it is a long standing concept that [`A` means the decimal numerical value of `10`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/bc.html#tag_20_09_13_03):

> When either ibase or obase is assigned a single digit value from the list in Lexical Conventions in bc, the value shall be assumed in hexadecimal. (For example, ibase=A sets to base ten, regardless of the current ibase value.).

That allows the reset of the input base to decimal 10 regardless of the base active at that point, that is: `ibase=A` always works to reset ibase to `10`.

Depending on the version of `bc` in use, the following digits `B` thru `Z` might be defined to have some specific value, none, or generate an error.

In specific, for GNU bc version 1.07 the value of a **single** upper case letter goes up to 35 (no matter which IBASE has been set).

```
$ echo $(bc <<<'A;B;C;D;E;F;G;H;I;Z')
10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 35
```

But for **double**, **triple**, etc uppercase digits the value is limited to be `ibase-1`.

```
$ echo $(bc <<<'AA;BB;GG;ZZ;AAA;ZZZ')
99 99 99 99 999 999

$ echo $(bc <<<'ibase=14;obase=ibase;AA;BB;GG;ZZ;AAA;ZZZ')
AA BB DD DD AAA DDD
```

#### Math PI

The value of the mathematical constant *pi* (or its usual symbol **π**) might be calculated with:

```
$ bc -l <<<'scale=40; 4*a(1)'
3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841968
```

Or, to set a variable:

```
bc -l <<<'scale=40; pi=4*a(1); pi'
3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841968
```